# Splitting a pivotchart from power pivot into multiple charts

Tags: excel, charts, powerpivot, powerquery

I have a pivot chart that tracks resource allocations based on a few filters. I would like to split the chart into multiple charts. In the picture, I want one chart for each line. I can do this manually (one chart for each resource) but that's not ideal because I only want to see certain charts based on the filters, and the data will change frequently.

Thanks in advance for help.

reference - https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdvG2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Blake**, unfortunately, this is not possible. Chart based on (power)pivot table is always linked  and if you update the pivot table, you will see the change instantly happen to the chart as well.

What I would suggest is to create four (or more) **different pivots** and then four (or more) linked pivot-based charts.

If there is any filter that needs to be used in all of the pivot tables, you can then use **[slicers](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Read-more-249f966b-a9d5-4b0f-b31a-12651785d29d) which can be linked to more than 1 pivot table**.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the conclusion that I also came to, and decided that just using slicers was more efficient than creating hundreds of pivot tables manually.